# Eclipse not seeing android device

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been testing my application on a samsung galaxy s2 for the last few months and everything worked just fine up until yesterday, now eclipse won't see the device, and the device won't offer the option of mounting the sdcard when I plug it in. I'm developing on a Mac, and the mobile offers to mount the sdcard when I plug into my friends windows machine (using the same wire). I've tried repeatedly restarting both the mac and the mobile, changing usb port (things which normally fix weird errors with eclipse). I'm really struggling with this, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the option 'USB-debugging' selected?

Comment: @Niek Yes I have, I've dried disabling/re-enabling it to no avail :(

Comment: Does the device show up when you do run adb devices from a command line?

Comment: @hooked82 No it doesn't, all it does is charge over the USB cable as far as I can tell..

Comment: Also (I'm not sure), when you've set the option to use ADB over WIFI on your phone, the device will not be recognized when you connect it with the cable. Did you perhaps use this feature in the past? If so, turn it off first. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: If it's not showing up in the list of devices, then go to Device Manager and see if it's showing up as an Android USB ADB Interface.  If not, you may need to re-install the drivers as somewhere along the lines, something changed.

Comment: @hooked82 the device is not showing up. I tried reinstalling the drivers anyway, the device comes up with MTP Application when I plug it in, but there's still no option no mount nor is there a new device recognised from my mac :(

Comment: Update: The phone refuses to mount on any macbook, but it will on windows and linux machines.

Comment: Did a factory reset and wiped the memory card, started working fine and I was able to run the project through eclipse, the same problem occurred a day later. I think there might be some hardware damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that my micro-usb port had rusted! I didn't find out until I shone a high powered light and saw the port had turned red-brown. Kind of weird since I haven't got it wet or anything :S